# how to use/allow page up in guake?

Tags: debian, guake

Is there a way to allow page up to scroll output one page up in guake. The only way right now is to use mouse-scroll but it would be more convenient if it can be keyboard based.

Guake - 3.3.0 on Debian testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to scroll via the keybindings <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd>?

You should also be able to scroll line by line using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> respectively.

You may need to install `gconf` or go into your settings to setup/change keybindings to what you wish.